# How many sides do the dice in Mash's boardgame have?

Tags: mashle-magic-and-muscles

In 'Rayne Ames and God's Gift' (Season 2, episode 3 of Mashle: Magic and Muscles) Mash plays a board game with his friends. I don't have the time stamp.

I noticed the dice they used had several more sides than I expected or am used to. Maybe about 60?

But it had numbers over 60 on at least one side.

How many sides did it have?

Comment: Like this https://www.amazon.com/Dice-Lab-60-sided-120-sided-Blue/dp/B01LY28TIT ?   Adding details about which episode and the time stamp to your question would help.  Is it Mashle: Magic and Muscles: Season 2, Episode 3

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yes, that's the episode number matching the title and the tag. I don't have the timestamp unfortunately.